# Construct id in constructor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, persistence

I have a table which have id that constructed from a combination of few fields. 
The id is a combination of name, code, and dateOfProduce (with certain format).

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private Date dateOfProduce;

    final private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

     public Product(String name, String code, Date dateOfProduce) {
        id = name + "-" + code + "-" + simpleDateFormat.format(dateOfProduce);
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.dateOfProduce = dateOfProduce;
     }
}
```

Will the id generated in the constructor be acceptable as best practise?

Comment: Not if you need unique IDs.

Comment: It's always recommended to generate an arbitrary key (`Long` or `UUID`). Among many other things, those perform much more efficiently than strings, since they're numbers of a fixed size.

Comment: I guess, customer is not a good example. I've updated the class name to be Product.
The combination of these fields are guaranteed to be unique as there's only 1 product a day with the combination of name and code.
That's a reason why we need to create this id. 
But where should I create this id? Constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this practice is what if people have the same first name, nickname, and DOB?

IDs are usually meant to be unique **id**etnifiers. Ideally you should generate them in a way that no two conflict. This one can, fairly easily. Imagine common nicknames like "Dick" for "Richard".

You can look into the [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class for this, or even go as far as something like [snowflakes](https://github.com/downgoon/snowflake). Or roll your own.